# Is it possible to integrate this function without using spherical coordinates?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, mathematical-physics, volume

I am looking to solve the integral

${\int\int\int{\rm e}^{-\sqrt {{x}^{2}+{y}^{2}+{z}^{2}}}} dxdydz$

My boundary conditions are the boundaries of a cube (not nicely aligned with the origin), so I'd like to avoid muddying the waters with spherical coordinates.

Any advice?

If you're interested, I'm essentially trying to solve the following problem.

I'm holding a flashlight underwater in a cubic swimming pool, what's the total amount of light being absorbed by the pool, assuming that some light escapes the pool? Treat the flashlight as an isotropic point source of light.

Attenuation of a beam in 1D is given by a simple exponential decay.

Answer (score -1):

$\int \exp{(- \sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2} ) } dx$

$ u = x^2 + y^2 + z^2$

$ du = 2x dx$

$ dx = du/2x$

$\int (\exp{(- \sqrt{u} ) }/u)  du =2 Ei(-\sqrt{u}) + C$ with $Ei(x)$ being the [Exponential Integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ExponentialIntegral.html)

Comment: Thanks for that, does that work though? Wolfram Alpha seems to be unable to solve an integral that should be solvable using your method. http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+exp(-sqrt(x%5E2%2B1))

Comment: @KnowingIsHalfTheBattle It works if $u = x^2 + y^2 + z^2$ is a valid change of variable. $y^2 + z^2$ is a constant in our problem, so we are left with $u = x^2 + C$.You can read more about it here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution

Comment: So how would you then do the dy and dz steps? Sorry if I'm being dense, i'm not used to Ei notation

Comment: I don't really know when I think of it. I would remove the integral since in 1D is constant, but I am not sure it works.